# issue setting up hadoop on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm running a single cluster hadoop on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I followed the guide at the following [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) step by step. 
When I try step 5 of execution, and run this comand (in hadoop-2.7.3 directory ):

```
$ bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input
```

I have this warnings messages but I don't know why:

```
17/04/11 14:14:16 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:546)
17/04/11 14:14:16 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:546)
17/04/11 14:14:16 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:546)
17/04/11 14:14:16 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeInternal(DFSOutputStream.java:577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:573)
17/04/11 14:14:16 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeInternal(DFSOutputStream.java:577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:573)
17/04/11 14:14:16 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:546)
17/04/11 14:14:16 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeInternal(DFSOutputStream.java:577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:573)
17/04/11 14:14:17 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:546)
17/04/11 14:14:17 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeInternal(DFSOutputStream.java:577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:573)
17/04/11 14:14:18 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeInternal(DFSOutputStream.java:577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:573)
17/04/11 14:14:18 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:546)
```

The problem is in the step 6, when I run the command:

```
$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

At some point in the output there is another warning which causes the failure of the command and the algorithm. I provide a piece of output (where error appears):

```
17/04/11 14:15:57 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
17/04/11 14:15:57 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1517099600_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /user/utente/input/hadoop
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1828)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1799)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:588)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /user/utente/input/hadoop
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1828)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1799)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:588)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): Path is not a file: /user/utente/input/hadoop
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1828)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1799)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:588)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1226)
    ... 21 more
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1517099600_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 23
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=9818273
        FILE: Number of bytes written=17083423
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=1686392
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=957
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=29
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=2069
        Map output records=24
        Map output bytes=590
        Map output materialized bytes=513
        Input split bytes=3534
        Combine input records=24
        Combine output records=13
        Spilled Records=13
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=1579
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=4616384512
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=76867
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 0
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:0
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1820796076_0002
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1820796076_0002
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for reduce tasks
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1820796076_0002_r_000000_0
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: Using ShuffleConsumerPlugin: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle@259b8adf
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: MergerManager: memoryLimit=363285696, maxSingleShuffleLimit=90821424, mergeThreshold=239768576, ioSortFactor=10, memToMemMergeOutputsThreshold=10
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO reduce.EventFetcher: attempt_local1820796076_0002_r_000000_0 Thread started: EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO reduce.EventFetcher: EventFetcher is interrupted.. Returning
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: finalMerge called with 0 in-memory map-outputs and 0 on-disk map-outputs
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merging 0 files, 0 bytes from disk
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merging 0 segments, 0 bytes from memory into reduce
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 0 sorted segments
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 0 segments left of total size: 0 bytes
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1820796076_0002_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local1820796076_0002_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local1820796076_0002_r_000000_0' to hdfs://localhost:9000/user/utente/output/_temporary/0/task_local1820796076_0002_r_000000
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1820796076_0002_r_000000_0' done.
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1820796076_0002_r_000000_0
17/04/11 14:15:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce task executor complete.
17/04/11 14:15:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1820796076_0002 running in uber mode : false
17/04/11 14:15:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 100%
17/04/11 14:15:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1820796076_0002 completed successfully
17/04/11 14:15:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 29
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=657731
        FILE: Number of bytes written=1171699
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=76867
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=68
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=5
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=0
        Reduce shuffle bytes=0
        Reduce input records=0
        Reduce output records=0
        Spilled Records=0
        Shuffled Maps =0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=153624576
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0
```

I do not know what went wrong. My version of java is (oracle version):

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

and Hadoop version is 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Can someone help me, please?

---

UPDATE 1:

I formatted the system and run the command:

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar grep input/hadoop output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

where I used *input/hadoop* instead of *input* but I have this error:

```
17/04/12 14:38:13 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
17/04/12 14:38:13 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
17/04/12 14:38:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-utente/mapred/staging/utente1761874612/.staging/job_local1761874612_0001
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/utente/input/hadoop
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep.run(Grep.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep.main(Grep.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I think I have some configuration problem but do not know where

Comment: 1) The Warnings can be ignored, it is a bug. 2) the `input` directory has a sub-directory called `hadoop`, trying passing `input/hadoop/` as the input path to the mapreduce.

Comment: I try to do as you said but Namenode fails to boot up

Comment: Yesterday was working properly. Today when I run `sbin/start-dfs.sh` and then `bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'` I have `17/04/12 12:33:10 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
java.net.ConnectException: Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connessione rifiutata; . When I stop the services, I have this output: `Stopping namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: no namenode to stop`

Comment: You have some configuration issues. Check the namenode logs, it would point out where the issue is.

Comment: In namenode logs I found this warning: `WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources.ExceptionHandler: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException`

Comment: When you say *single cluster", you mean "single node"? In pseudo-distributed mode?

Comment: I mean single node and Pseudo-Distributed Mode